# Python mypy don't type check dataclass

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

mypy works perfectly with type hints but when I use a dataclass as return type it don't check the type

My command : `python -m pipenv run mypy .`

```py
@dataclass
class HttpMessageModel:
    message: str
    code: int

def http_message(message: str) -> HttpMessageModel:
    return {
        "message": message,
        "code": "200", # --> should fail since we have a int
    }
```

full code exemple : https://github.com/TheSmartMonkey/create-python-app

Comment: It should fail as well because you're not returning an instance of the `dataclass`. It seems like you want a `TypedDict` instead of a `dataclass`.

Comment: I tryed this `class HttpMessageModel(TypedDict)` and it don't seem's to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I put your code in a single file:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class HttpMessageModel:
    message: str
    code: int

def http_message(message: str) -> HttpMessageModel:
    return {
        "message": message,
        "code": "200", # --> should fail since we have a int
    }
```

and run `mypy` on it, I do get the expected error:

```
C:\test\python>mypy test.py
test.py:9: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Dict[str, str]", expected "HttpMessageModel")
```

The problem with checking your actual project might be in how the directory structure is set up.  Take a look at https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running_mypy.html#mapping-file-paths-to-modules and try either adding `__init__.py` files at the root of your package directories or adding `namespace_packages = True` to your mypy config.

Note that to return an `HttpMessageModel` instead of a `dict`, your function should do:

```
def http_message(message: str) -> HttpMessageModel:
    return HttpMessageModel(message, 200)
```

Comment: I've add `namespace_packages=true` and `explicit_package_bases=true` in my `setup.cfg` file and refactor the http_message method as you said and it worked ! thanks a lot !